# How to toggle only the clicked element while using jsrender scripts?

Tags: jquery, html, jsrender

This is my **HTML code**:

```
<li>
    <div class="search-res-title clearfix">
          <h3> <a href="food-details.html?item={{>_source.name}}" > {{>_source.name}}</a> </h3> <span><i class="badge">{{>_source.items.length}}</i>Places</span> 
          </div>

        <ul class="sr-itemlist">
        {{for _source.items}}
                <li> <a href="restaurant-page.html?restaurant={{>hotelDetails.key}}" > {{>hotelDetails.name}}</a> <i class="badge">{{>hotelDetails.misc.rating}}</i> </li>
        {{if #index ==2}}
         </ul>
        <div class="item-serh-more test{{:#index}} extra-list clearfix" >
            <ul class="sr-itemlist">
        {{/if}}
        {{/for}}
            </ul>
        {{if _source.items.length >=2 }}
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        <a href="#" class="loc-showbtn" refVal="{{:#index}}">more<span class="caret"></span></a>
    </li>
</script>
```

Now, this is my **jQuery code**

```
var showMore = function () {
 $('body').on('click', '.loc-showbtn', function () {
  $('.item-serh-more').toggle();
    });
  };
```

**What I want is:**
When I click the `".loc-showbtn"` i want individual element to open.

**What happens now is:**
When I click the `".loc-showbtn"`,the entire elements with class "              `$('.item-serh-more').toggle();"` opens up.

I tried giving index number of the jsrender loop to the class `".item-serh-more"`. But it seems not working.

Comment: Instead of using JsRender and then doing DOM manipulation, you could consider using a more data-driven approach, by adding data-binding to JsRender - with JsViews. This sample may give you some ideas: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/range. BTW the {{range}} tag can also be used just with JsRender: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/tags/extend-for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div required for toggling is the previous sibling of clicked anchor. you can simply use `.prev()` with clicked elements context `this` to target it:

```
$('body').on('click', '.loc-showbtn', function () {
  $(this).prev().toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the selector `$('.item-serh-more')` used in the click handler, it selects all elements with the class `item-serh-more` but what you need is the `item-serh-more` element which is the previous sibling of the clicked `loc-showbtn` element.

```
var showMore = function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.loc-showbtn', function () {
        $(this).prev('.item-serh-more').toggle();
    });
};
```